# Expression Blend doesn't load project

Tags: windows-phone-7, sdk, expression-blend

Suddenly my Expression Blend won't work anymore. I am working on an App in *VS for WP*7 and when I try to open that project in Blend, the interface gets loaded and the title-bar of Blend says that my .sln file is there - but nothing is showing up.

Every panel is empty.

I tried rebuilding my project in VS but that didn't help. 
I am using Expr. Blend 4.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Allright, I got it.
It seems a little ridiculous, but

I had to go the projects tab, which is on the left side in E.Blend. From there I chose my main xaml page and Blend loaded my project.